# Using 有 in comparing actions

Tags: sentence-structure, comparison

I search for comparisons using 有 and this page says [that](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_comparable_degree_with_%22you%22). I have 2 questions.

1/ It is said that 有 comparison pattern is just used in questions, **not statements.** Is it true？If it is wrong, can I use 有 to make statements in the writing?

2/ I wonder if using 有 in comparing actions is **the same as** 比 comparison structure. Is those sentences correct？
她做饭比我做得好多了 = 她有我做饭做得好多了。

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"她做饭有我做得那麼好嗎?"(Does she cook as good a I do?). It is not a just a comparison. It is also an 'indication of degree'

> 她做饭 = She cooks (topic)
>
> 有 = have
>
> 我做得那麼好嗎? (我做得那麼好 is a relative phrase that indicate degree)
>
> *The degree of 'as good as I doing it?'*

You can say "她做饭有我做得那麼好"  or "她做饭没有我做得那麼好" as a statement.  (indication of degree)

> 她有我做饭做得好多了

It is not logical to state '有' (have the same level) and then state '好多了' (much better). It is either 'have the same level' or 'much better'. You can't state both.

It has to be:

[X 比 Y 好多了] = Compare to Y, X is much better

[X 有 Y 那麼好] = X is as good as Y

Comment: wow I got it. Thank you so much :D